# Summing a range of cells across different workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, sum, range

struggling to conquer this one myself. The essence of the problem is as follows:

I have a list of workbooks that have identically named and identically structured worksheets within them. I would like to take a particular cell from within each workbook, sum across the workbooks, and place the total in the same cell of another identically structured workbook.

The list of workbooks to sum across is quite long. I do not need to do it for all cells, but there will be about 15 different ranges on 15 different sheets that I do need to do it for.

If possible I would also like the links to be added rather than the numbers. For example in cellA1 of the total workbook it would read 
`= [workbook(1)]1!A1 + [workbook(2)]1!A1 + ...` although I am not sure this can be done.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you go to the total cell on the last workbook and star writting `=` and then you can go workbook after workbook selecting the cell you need and in between using the `+` that would end your problem. Thought to update the result you'd need to open all the workbooks every time.

Comment: There are lots of workbooks, and I would like it to be dynamic and done by code as need to do this quite regularly. I would like to pull the list of workbooks to be summed from another workbok.

Comment: Then as Carlos said, @JordanMartin you should provide us with some work of yours. I'd recommend you starting with the `Record Macro` feature and then check what VBA gives you.